# I need a specific code part to work with a radio type instead of button

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the code from W3 to filter products on a webpage. [LINK TO W3 CODE](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp)

The code uses buttons to filter out products with specific tags on them. Now the problem is, instad of buttons, I am using radio buttons. which is working just fine, until I go to another page and back to the product page. Because when I go the another page, and back, the radio buttons is still active on the previously selected radio button, and not on "Select All" by default. THe filtering has reset, but not the radio button. Below I will paste the code I have used:

```
HTML:

<div class="products-filter">

  <h3 class="filter-headers">Brands</h3>

    <label class="container active">Select All
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio", onclick="filterSelection('all')">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container">Doosan
      <input type="radio" name="radio", onclick="filterSelection('doosan')">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>..... AND SO ON.

Javascript:

filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("products");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "product-show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "product-show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "product-show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("products-filter");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("container");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

I hope its clear what I need? I need the radio button "Select All" to be selected by default when you go back on the page.

Thakn you

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="filter" class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')" value="Show all" checked="checked"  />
  <input type="radio" class="btn" name="filter" onclick="filterSelection('cars')" value="Cars" />
  <input type="radio" class="btn" name="filter" onclick="filterSelection('animals')" value="Animals" />
  <input type="radio" class="btn" name="filter" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')" vlaue="Fruits" />
  <input type="radio" class="btn" name="filter" onclick="filterSelection('colors')" value="Colors" />
</div>
```

all you are missing is checked attribute in input with type radio.

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked">
```

Comment: dosent work sadly, I have checked attribute already, in my input type radio. has always been there. It does work, but if I choose a category other than "Select All" and jump to another page and back, its stays on the other category and not on "Select All" by default.
Wierd thing is, that when I do go back from another page, the "Select All" is active, but only for a split second, before jumping back to another category.

Comment: Is it single page web application?